# How to set default value in column if null in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to find a way to set a default value for nulls in my column in Azure data factory. Here is my current output and attached also is my dataflow and pipeline.

I want to set a default value to display in place of nulls using Azure data factory

[Myoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn3aY.png)

[Dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQCRT.png)

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2NeE.png)

Comment: Does [iifNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#iifnull) helps with your case?

Comment: Unfortunately no it does not

Comment: why not? iifNull is exactly what you need here.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1:** You can use iif() function and isNull() function to achieve your  requirement.

In below example, I am trying to use iif() and isNull() to check is my 'Fee' column null. And if my Fee column has null in it then I am replacing it with "0.00". as in my case the Fee Column has decimal values.

**Note: We should use this inside derived column transformation.**

**Expression:** iif(isNull(Fee),toDecimal(0.00),toDecimal(Fee))
[image]

**Approach 2:** You can use iifNull() function to achieve your  requirement.
In below example, I am trying to use iifNull() to check is my 'Fee' column null. And if my Fee column has null in it then I am replacing it with "0.00".
Please Note, we should use this inside derived column transformation.

**Expression:** iifNull(Fee,toDecimal(0.00))
[image]